# Dictionary without repetitive values

Tags: python

In my script, I want to include a key in my dictionary and create a condition where, if I already have a repetitive value for the same key, it will not be included.

FIle to use as an example:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/felipelira/files_to_test/master/GCF_000302915.1_Pav631_1.0_genomic.gbff

```
for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(input_file, "genbank"):
    description = seq_record.description
    for seq_feature in seq_record.features:
        if seq_feature.type=="source":
            try:
                source = seq_feature.qualifiers['organism'][0]
            except (KeyError, IndexError):
                source = 'n/a'

            try: 
                strain = seq_feature.qualifiers['strain'][0]
            except (KeyError, IndexError):
                strain = 'n/a'
                    if source not in dict1.keys():
                        dict1[source] = [value]
                        #print description +'\t'+ source +'\t'+ '\t'.join(value)
                    else:
                        if source in dict1.keys() and value != dict1[source]:   
                            dict1[source].append(value)
                        #print description +'\t'+source +'\t'+ '\t'.join(value)

        for k, v in dict1.iteritems():
            print k, v
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to append only if `dict1[source]` doesn't contain `value`? You can use the `in` operator for that

Comment: Please create an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I don't want to include the value if my Key already has this value.

Comment: What's the difference between overwriting the old value with the same value and not saving the new value? The net result should be the same, no?

Comment: Fragmented genomes have the same descriptors and it is not important for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace `!=` with `not in`, i.e:

```
        try: 
            strain = seq_feature.qualifiers['strain'][0]
        except (KeyError, IndexError):
            strain = 'n/a'
                if source not in dict1.keys():
                    dict1[source] = [value]
                    #print description +'\t'+ source +'\t'+ '\t'.join(value)
                else:
                    if source in dict1.keys() and value not in dict1[source]:   
                        dict1[source].append(value)
                    #print description +'\t'+source +'\t'+ '\t'.join(value)
```

Comment: `source in dict1.keys()` can be removed - it is always true in this case

Comment: @Dunno Yeah, you're right, `if value not in dict1[source]` is enough

Answer (score 1):

In order to not add a value to a list that already contains this value, you can check for membership using the `in` operator. Like this:

```
if not value in dict1[source]:   
    dict1[source].append(value)
```

If you don't need your dictionary values to be lists, consider using a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) which is optimised for keeping its members unique.